# Meaning and usage of ‘other than’?

Tags: prepositional-objects

I have questions about 'other than'...

> She couldn’t do anything about her bad luck **other than suffer** through it.

1) What’s the exact meaning and usage of 'other than' in this sentence?

2) Isn’t it a preposition? Then why use 'suffer' instead of 'suffering'?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a phrasal preposition that means except ([Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/other%20than)).

We can use 'suffer' if there are any modal verbs before it; could is a modal verb that takes the present form of the verb coming after it, as in:

> - “She **could** not **do** anything about her bad luck other than **suffer** through it.” **[see 'do' and 'suffer' following the modal verb could. Using doing and suffering would entirely be ungrammatical here.]**

To consider your example more analytical, you can say:

> - “She **could** not **do** anything about her bad luck, but (she) could **suffer** through it.”

Thus, don't say 'doing' or 'suffering' like this:

> - “She couldn’t **doing** anything about her bad luck other than **suffering** through it.”

Comment: @ellie Or, if you reverse the logic of the sentence, *The only thing she could do about her bad luck was suffer through it*.